# Creating custom WAI-ARIA role

Tags: role, wai-aria

I am new to WAI-ARIA. I want to know how can we create a custom role based on the existing roles.

For example, i want to create a custom button role from aria button role. It will be great, if any one provide steps to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Custom roles are not supported in WAI-ARIA 1.0, although there is infrastructure within ARIA that could support this in future. From https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.0/roles:

> 5. The Roles Model
>
> [...]
>
> The RDF/OWL taxonomy *may be used as a vehicle to extend WAI-ARIA in the future* or by tool manufacturers to validate states and properties applicable to roles per this specification.

For now, stick to the closest defined role; likely button in your case.

In your case, what is it about your button that requires a custom role? How does it differ in behavior from a regular button?